# Getting arguments out of regexp

Tags: regex, clojure

I want it to return 450 in some way, the $1 is just a silly variable name. It's like the reverse of format. What is the clojure regex magic for achieving this?

```
(re-something #"$1\sUSD" "450 USD")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
user=> (re-find #"(\d\d\d) (USD)" "450 USD")
["450 USD" "450" "USD"]
user=> (nth *1 1)
"450"
```

Answer (score 6):

I like to use re-find, if-let and destructuring. I very often write parsing code in the following pattern:

```
(def currency-regex #"(\d+) ([A-Z]{3})")

(defn parse-currency [s]
  (if-let [[_ amount currency] (re-find currency-regex s)]
    (process amount currency)
    (signal-error s)))
```

Answer (score 4):

I find myself using this structure a lot to match my first group in a regex:

```
(second (re-find #"foo(bar)" "This is a foobar example"))
;=> "bar"
```

...because more often than not, I'm just capturing one item, like you are with the numerals. To make your code read better, you could alias the `second` function for this situation, so your intent is clear:

```
(def first-match second)
(first-match (re-find #"foo(bar)" "This is a foobar example"))
;=> "bar"
```

Maybe `first-match` could be `first-group` to be more precise, but you get the idea. Now the intent of picking out the second item from the return value of `re-find` is clearer.